# Image is multiplicate

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried to make my website responsive but when I drag the widows to see the result, the background just multiplicate. I have 2 images as background(1 at the start and 1 at the bottom)

I tried

```
@media screen and (max-width : 1600px) { 
  .bg1{
   background-size: 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
}
```

and if I do that I will get just some while space between images.

HTML:

```
    <div class="bg1">
           *some content here*
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
    @media screen and (max-width : 1600px) { 
      .titlu h1{ font-size: 20rem; }
      .navbar li a{
       font-size: 20px;
      }
      .bg1{
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Can you show us a working example in a snippet? That said, perhaps `background-size: cover` may help you.

Comment: background-position property might also help if the area you want to show is not looking good. You might want to try background-position:center;

Comment: Here it is, try to minimize the window and the image will multiplicate https://jsfiddle.net/z7xyjb1a/

Comment: The code in your fiddle differs from what you posted above. Specifically the `background-repeat: no-repeat;` is missing from the fiddle, and when added, fixes the issue.

Comment: In the fiddle you have 2 divs with backgrounds on each. the 100% value will cover the 100% of the div not the screen. the second background is always there but you only see it when you minimize the windows. so tell me what you want to do exactly I'll try to help you

Comment: @j08691 only thing is that now I have some white space https://jsfiddle.net/80tfyzmp/

Comment: Are you referring to the gap around the image? If so that's the margin on the body element. You can get rid of that with `body{margin:0}`

Comment: @EvikGhazarian So instead of what you see in those pics https://imgur.com/a/mKn2kan I want to make the image to be responive on the whole screen, because only the width is resposive.
I don't know If is clear what I said, Im a newbie.

Comment: So you want width to be responsive. and image to be in the middle of the screen?

Comment: @EvikGhazarian  No I want it on height.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `background-position` to place your image and `background-repeat` to avoid repetition

```css
@media screen and (max-width : 1600px) {
  .bg1 {
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
}
```